# python-sphinx - Display only function signature with autodoc?

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

In Sphinx is possible to include the signature of a function or method *manually* using the `py:function` (or `py:method`) directive:

```
.. py:function:: my_func(data, named=None, *args, *kwargs)
```

It is also possible to use `autodoc` directives to include and format the whole docstring of a function or method:

```
.. automethod:: my_func
```

I am wondering if there is a way of configuring `autodoc` to include and format only the signature, without the rest of the docstring, so that I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See autodoc's [sphinx.ext.autodoc.between](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#sphinx.ext.autodoc.between).

> Return a listener that either keeps, or if *exclude* is True excludes, lines between lines that match the *marker* regular expression. If no line matches, the resulting docstring would be empty, so no change will be made unless *keepempty* is true.
>
> If *what* is a sequence of strings, only docstrings of a type in *what* will be processed.

Answer (score 2):

autodoc-process-signature can be used here as well.

```
def process_signature(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    return modified_signature, modified_return_annotation
    # will be rendered to method(modified_signature) -> modified_return_annotation

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-signature", process_signature)
```

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/ext/autodoc.html